# Good Resources to Learn About the $p$ Adic Solenoid?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently studying $p$ adic analysis, and wanted to know if there were good papers or books to read more about the $p$ adic solenoid, preferably its construction and physical structure?

I am familiar with Alain Robert's book and his exposition on the solenoid, but I tried looking for more information online and I didn't find anything substantial.  Any other suggestions are very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I admit that Robert's book is the only place where I have ever seen that object.

Comment: I still have not found an exposition at the level, or exceeding the level of Robert's exposition.  It's odd, since I wonder where Robert found this information to begin with....

Comment: "Solenoids" go back to the 1940s it seems. (Cf. https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/12_1_adeles.pdf, https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes/02_solenoids.pdf, https://www.math.uvic.ca/~buricd/SolenoidTalk.pdf, http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/padicsolenoid.pdf.) It's not impossible that Robert was the first to study and give a name to that "$p$-adic solenoid".

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg the term "$p$-adic solenoid" was around before Robert's book.

Comment: I have good news! The book "the structure of compact groups" by Hofmann and Morris seems to have some additional material on the solenoid, including a nice drawing!

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a passing reference to the p-adic solenoid in Emily Riehl's book, Categories in Context (p.1). Apparently it came up in Eilenberg and Mac Lane's work leading to the universal coefficient theorem, which later led to them initiating category theory. The reference she gives is to Mac Lane's 2005 autobiography.

Comment: It's true that MacLane mentions it in his autobiography but there are no details or information on it in that book.